# How to redirect to a html page from a java servlet along with the variables from the servlet?

Tags: java, html, servlets

I want to open a html page from my java servlet and the variables of that servlet should be used to assign the form fields in the html page which is to be opened.

This is my servlet

```
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.net.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
public class SignIn extends HttpServlet
{
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res)throws IOException,ServletException
{
    PrintWriter pw=res.getWriter();
    String fname=null,lname=null,uname,pwd,dept=null,mobno=null;

    Connection con=null;
    Statement stat=null;
    ResultSet rs=null;
    try
    {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:userdb");
        stat=con.createStatement();
            uname=req.getParameter("un");
            pwd=req.getParameter("password");
            //pw.println(pwd);



    rs=stat.executeQuery("select * from userdb where uname= '"+uname+"' and pwd='"+pwd+"'");

                while(rs.next())
                {

                    fname=rs.getString("fname");
                    lname=rs.getString("lname");
                    dept=rs.getString("dept");
                    mobno=rs.getString("mobno");
                }

    //pw.println(fname+" "+lname+" "+dept+" "+mobno); 

    //I want to pass the above four variables (fname, lname, dept, mobno) to   an html page and assign these to a form field in html page and I need to open that html page from this servlet

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        pw.println(e.toString());
    }
}
}
```

This is my html page which i want to open from the servlet

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"href="sty2.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div id="bg"><img src="bg.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" alt=""></div>
<div id="content">

<form name="data" action="">

<div id="header">
<h1>TEXT</h1>
</div>

<div id="header1">
<h2> WELCOME </h2>
</div>
<div id="header2">
<input type="button" name="logout" value="Logout" id="dlbutton"  onClick="window.open('Main.html')"/>
</div>

<div id="nav">
<br/>
First Name:<br/><br/>
Last Name:<br/><br/>
Department :<br/><br/>
Mobile No.:<br/><br/>
</div>
<div id="section">
<br/>
<input class="textbox" type="text" name="fn" placeholder="first name" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'first name'"/><br/>    <br/>
<input class="textbox" type="text" name="ln" placeholder="last name" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'last name'" /><br/><br/>
<input class="textbox" type="text" name="dn" placeholder="dept name" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'dept name'" /><br/><br/>
<input class="textbox" type="text" name="mn" placeholder="mobile number" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'mobile number'" /><br/><br/>
</div>
<div id="footer">
<input type="submit" name="update" value="Update" id="dlbutton"/>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

How to achieve this?? Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: buddy that term is called `AJAX`

Comment: learn servlets and JSP!!

Comment: Do you want to redirect to some other HTML Page from your servlet? is that HTML page rendered by you?

Comment: Post has been updated!! Any help would be appreciated!! Thanks in advance!! :)

Comment: @BhargavModi I dont want to change my web page without reloading it... I want to redirect it to another page which holds the result of the processed data of my current page..

Answer (score 0):

Redirect will send a message to the browser telling it to send a get request request for a different url
So if you want data from the current request, you either have to include it as a query string in the redirect URL or save on in the session so the subsequent request can retrieve it.

An alternative is to use a forward which will call another URL  and include the response in the response for the current request.

Embedding field values dynamically in the html page requires a technology like JSP, have a look at [this](http://www.jsptut.com/). You need a JSP engine like Tomcat or Jetty and then:

- rename your .html to .jsp
- Add `value='<%= request.fname %>"` or similar to each of your `<input >` tags

Then in your servlet you could do a redirect by:

```
response.setStatus (303);
response.setHeader ("Location", jsppath+"? fname="+fname+"&lname="+lname+"&dept="+dept+"&mobno="+mobno);
```

This would be a rather odd JSP implementation as it is a bit inside out. As [prashant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2987706/prashant) said you should spend some time learning JSP. or better still look at JavaEE 6 or later including JSF.

JSP is simpler to learn than JSF but JavaEE 6 is well worth the time.

It does look a bit like you need a dynamic Web application framework like JavaEE to do what you want.

Comment: How can I include the data as a query string in the redirect url?? and how can I retrieve it in my redirected html document? @redge

Comment: OK I miss understood your question. You don't want a redirect. You do want JSP or JSF like Prashant said. You could then forward or redirect to the JSP/JSF using ServletContext.getRequestDispatcher() the values need to be saved in the request or the session prior to the forward/redirect and the JSP/JSF can use them.

Comment: I cant get you... can u explain it in the code please? @redge